# iPhone:Animation move view controller upward

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iPhone application, where i need to move a first view controller slowly upward in animation and move to second view controller. I am thinking to use CoreAnimation for moving the first view controller slowly upward and push to next view controller. Could someone help on giving what are the classes/apis available to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:yourfirstview cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(remove_view)];
    //change frame here
    yourfirstview.frame =CGRectMake(0,-480,320,480);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

   -(void)remove_view
    {
       [yourfirstview removeFromSuperview];
       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
       [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:yoursecondview cache:YES];
       //change frame here
       yoursecondview.frame =CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
       [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to push to new view controller, not UIView. So, i want to use Core Animation (which has CATransition support for moving up) and commit animation and use pushViewController to move to next screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this on a single view controller using multiple `UIView`s

As per Apple's documentation:

> In iOS 4 and later, use the block-based animation methods.

So, in order to produce the intended results, using the following code.

```
UIView *mySecondView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480)];
[mySecondView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:mySecondView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:3.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    [mySecondView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -480)];
}completion:^(BOOL done){

}];
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to push to new view controller, not UIView.

Comment: @user213199 Pushing a view controller refers to moving a view to the left to reveal a new one on the right. This is done using a `UINavigationController`